# windows 8.1 - two minute without network after boot

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, windows-services, timeout, delay

I have noticed (without being able to determine when it started) that on a Windows 8.1 Pro with default, unmodified system settings, the system does not have network configured when the system reaches logon screen.
If I login at this stage, the desktop is frozen and unusable until the two minute timeout expires.

[image]

This takes exactly two minutes after each boot, then on the right side I can view the network connections names (lan, etc) while on the lower left corner the network icon changes to regular network-connected icon.

I'd like to restore default functionality without having to use "pc settings - update and recovery". What should I attempt to do?

Comment: What brand and model is the computer ? What have you tried to resolve this ?

Comment: How are you connecting - wired, wireless, router model ?

Comment: self-assembled pc, core2duo, onboard realtek 8168 with latest available drivers. I have not attempted anything since I've got no idea where to start. it's connecting wired to linux PC router via 1Gbps ethernet switch. monitoring from linux shows it does not ask for dhcp address until after the two minute delay.

Comment: Try to see if this is happening when [Booting in Safe mode](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/5-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-8-windows-81).

Comment: Use of course Safe mode with Network.

Comment: @CostinGușă I don't know why but I am feeling like asking what Antivirus are you using ?

Comment: no antivirus. safe mode with network gives worse situation - permanent red circle with cross network icon in the lower left corner, no response to icmp echo request, but replies to arp requests

Comment: correction to "does not ask for dhcp address until after the two minute delay" - it DOES ask for dhcp IP right when the gui comes up. but it does NOT reply to icmp echo request until after two minutes.

Comment: Something is very wrong here. Maybe you should check system integrity with [sfc /scannow](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/3047-sfc-scannow-command-run-windows-8-a.html).

Comment: `sfc /scannow` command & log file `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log` reports that all system files are intact

Comment: Check your drivers in Windows Update optional section and on manufacturer's website. Check also the Event Viewer for interesting messages.

Comment: what difference would new drivers make since I'm running the same drivers that were running since initial install when the issue was not present? event viewer shows only regular os informational messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions in the comments were leading to the wrong direction; meanwhile I have found the root cause: the Microsoft ISCSI Initiator Service.
Removed the target portal and re-added then manually chosen the LAN IP in the advanced settings - now the login screen immediately shows regular network info (no yellow or red warning/critical circles near the network icon).

Apparently the MS initiator does not like target reconfiguration during an active session, even if you dismount the mounted volume and logoff from the target - you must completely remove the portal host from the list of portals - and during boot it still insists on mounting the old target, which no longer exists, even if it's also gone from the GUI.

Comment: Have you created an iSCSI SAN or storage device across the network ?

Comment: By the way but unrelated to the issue, the MS iscsi initiator is aberrantly asking for dhcp using two hardcoded ethernet addresses, and never acknowledges back (just asks and does not respond back with DHCPACK):  

    May 16 18:50:52 router dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from e1:6c:d6:ae:52:90 via br0  

    May 16 18:50:53 router dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from e9:eb:b3:a6:db:3c via br0  

    May 16 18:50:53 router dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.1.24 to e1:6c:d6:ae:52:90 via br0  

    May 16 18:50:54 router dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.1.26 to e9:eb:b3:a6:db:3c via br0

Comment: @harrymc obviously yes, re-read the part where I say "removed the target portal" - this means removing something that priorly existed

Comment: Obviously yes in your answer, but how did you expect anyone to guess it from your post ?